# AES Encryption /Decryption code Javascript (In Browser)

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, cryptography

I need a JAVASCRIPT AES encryption and decryption of a string text with password as key. I have gathered code from online transformed according to what I know . Although working each time I run, the encrypted form of the same message and key/pass is different during each run. And at first encryption and decryption works good but when you do it second-time encrypted data is different from previous data of the same message and password/key. 
The code is below here. If anyone can transform into a working code it would be really helpful. My problem is each time different encryption data is provided for the same message and pass. And during the second decryption, the decrypted data is not full-sized, ie missing some strings. For easiness, I have used simple message, during the real run I was using a message - size of 128 characters and key/pass size of 216 characters.

```
 html>

 <title>
   Registration
 </title>

<body>

  <form name="prototype" onsubmit="pass()"  action="registration.html"  
    method="post">



        <br> 
            <br> 
    Custom Password <input id="passe" type="password" name="text2"> 
            <br>
         <br>






   <input type="submit"  value="Login" /> 

   </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="aes.js"></script>
    /* I use it like above but for your referecene  <script 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto- 
   js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"  >  </script> */

<script>




    function pass()
        {

     var message="hai",f,g;

      a=document.getElementById("passe").value; 
      f=encrypt(message,a);
      document.write("\n  <br> <br>  Encrypted  =  ",f); 
       g=decrypt(f,a);
       document.write("\n  <br> <br>  Decrypted  = ",g); 

        }


      function encrypt(message,key){
      var message = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key);
      return message.toString();
        }

     function decrypt(message,key){
     var code = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(message, key);
     var decryptedMessage = code.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
      return decryptedMessage;
        }

         </script>
         </body>
         </html>
```

Comment: The ciphertext is *supposed* to be different each time you encrypt, otherwise you can distinguish if the same (initial) plaintext blocks are encrypted each time. The way to accomplish this is to have a unique key / IV combination each time, usually by selecting a random one for each encryption operation. In your case however a salt is used to derive the key and IV, so both are probably unique each time. The salt could e.g. be prefixed to the ciphertext.

Comment: Is the ciphered text supposed to be different if you supply the same key and same message as input each time? I do not see where i am adding a salted text, could elaborate or show me? you don't have to unless salt is provided inside the javascript page. and finally, my decryption doesn't work correctly too so isn't that a problem? I mean we are storing the ciphered text and key for future use but if we cannot decrypt the ciphered text with the same key what use it has.

Comment: The library is providing the salt for you. Read the documentation! You're not encoding the ciphertext and it is basically random bytes, so that the decryption fails is not unexpected either. You can use base64url encoding for creating "ASCII" armor that doesn't have to be URL-escaped.